# How to treat tcl string as a hex number and convert it into binary?

Tags: tcl

I have a tcl string set in a variable. I want to treat it as a hex to convert into binary of it. Can anybody help me to achieve this.

Here is what i am doing :

```
$ /usr/bin/tclsh8.5
% set a a1a2a3a4a5a6
a1a2a3a4a5a6
% set b [ string range $a 0 3 ]
a1a2
```

Now i want that a1a2 value of variable "b" should be treated as 0xa1a2, so that i can convert it into binary. Please help me to solve this.

Comment: What do you want out of this? Numbers? A string of bytes? These are different (and Johannes gives the perfect answer for “string of bytes”).

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Tcl 8.6, then `binary decode hex` is the best choice:

```
binary decode hex $b
```

If you are using an older version of Tcl, then you have to use the `binary format` with the H format specifier:

```
binary format H* $b
```

You can write the resulting byte array to a file or send it through a socket etc, but if you want to display it as text, I suggest converting it to a string first:

```
encoding convertfrom utf-8 [binary format H* $b]
```